# JSoup issue with ancestor child operator to perform a selection

Tags: java, screen-scraping, jsoup

I'm attempting to scrape everything inside a div with the class of results-column.

**This is the code I'm using for my query, which is not returning any data:**

```
Elements el_name = doc.select(".div.results-column a.no-tracks.url"); 
Elements el_phone = doc.select(".div.results-column  span.business-phone.phone");
Elements el_address = doc.select(".div.results-column span.street-address");
Elements el_city = doc.select(".div.results-column span.locality");
Elements el_state = doc.select(".div.results-column span.region");
Elements el_postalcode = doc.select(".div.results-column span.postal-code");
```

The selector is outlined here: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

**Example:**

```
<div class='results-column'>
   <div class='listing-content'>
   <span class='business-phone phone'>(111) 222-333</span><br>
   <span class='no-tracks url'>www.example.com</span><br>
   <span class='street-address'>29129 Sesame Street</span><span class='locality'>, Sesame City</span><br>
   [Rest of information from result1 would be here, I don't need to list every single thing on SO I hope]
   </div>
   <span class='business-phone phone'>(111) 222-333</span><br>
   <span class='no-tracks url'>www.example.com</span><br>
   <span class='street-address'>29129 Sesame Street</span><span class='locality'>, Sesame City</span><br>
   [Rest of information from result2 would be here, I don't need to list every single thing on SO I hope]
   </div>
</div>
```

Can I not select a div of a certain class with the ancestor child operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
  doc.select("div.results-column a.no-tracks.url");
```

not

```
  doc.select(".div.results-column a.no-tracks.url");
```

A dot before token works as a class-selector. HTML tags go without dots (the same for other selectors).

Comment: Oh thank you for catching that for me. In their documents it says ".body", I never saw the word "class" in there until I re-read it just now after you said that. I was assuming the HTML element. I can't believe I spent hours re-reading that page and never saw that.